# Custom Capabilities for CPT and Problem with current_user_can()

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I have setup a CPT with custom capabilities.

```
add_action('init', 'fac_product_posttype_init');
function fac_product_posttype_init(){
    $product_labels = array( ... );
    $caps = array(
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_products',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_products',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_products',
            'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_products',
            'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_products',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_products',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_products',
            'edit_post' => 'edit_product',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_product',
            'read_post' => 'read_product',
            'upload_files' => 'upload_files'
        );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $product_labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'product',
        'capabilities' => $caps,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
        'has_archive' => 'products',
        'menu_position' => 5, 
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false
    ); 
    register_post_type('product',$args);
}
```

Then assigned those capabilities to `administrator` and `subscriber`

```
function fs_add_roles(){
    $roles_set = get_option('fs_roles_are_set');
    //if(!$roles_set){

    $admin = get_role('administrator');
    $admin->add_cap('publish_products');
    $admin->add_cap('edit_products');
    $admin->add_cap('delete_products');
    $admin->add_cap('edit_published_products');
    $admin->add_cap('delete_published_products');
    $admin->add_cap('edit_others_products');
    $admin->add_cap('delete_others_products');

    //update_option('fs_roles_are_set', true);

    $subscriber = get_role('subscriber');
    $subscriber->add_cap('publish_products');
    $subscriber->add_cap('edit_products');
    $subscriber->add_cap('delete_products');
    $subscriber->add_cap('edit_published_products');
    $subscriber->add_cap('delete_published_products');
    //}
}
add_action('init', 'fs_add_roles');
```

All good upto this point and I can see on `$wp_roles` global array that all those custom caps are set `true` for `administrator` and `subscriber`.

**BUT**

when I call `current_user_can('delete_product', $post_id);` it returns `false`. I have double checked the $post_id. Its created by the `$current_user`

I am trying to figure out the problem for hours. But not sure whats going on. Any advice on troubleshooting is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved!**

Meta Capabilities `edit_product`, `delete_product`, 'read_product` etc should be handled separately. Below code is from [Justin Tadlocks Site](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types)

```
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'fac_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );

function fac_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {

    /* If editing, deleting, or reading a product, get the post and post type object. */
    if ( 'edit_product' == $cap || 'delete_product' == $cap || 'read_product' == $cap ) {
        $post = get_post( $args[0] );
        $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

        /* Set an empty array for the caps. */
        $caps = array();
    }

    /* If editing a product, assign the required capability. */
    if ( 'edit_product' == $cap ) {
        if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_posts;
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_others_posts;
    }

    /* If deleting a product, assign the required capability. */
    elseif ( 'delete_product' == $cap ) {
        if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_posts;
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_others_posts;
    }

    /* If reading a private product, assign the required capability. */
    elseif ( 'read_product' == $cap ) {

        if ( 'private' != $post->post_status )
            $caps[] = 'read';
        elseif ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = 'read';
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->read_private_posts;
    }

    /* Return the capabilities required by the user. */
    return $caps;
}
```